# How to prevent race condition of different `navigate`s?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, reach-router

[Github issue](https://github.com/reach/router/issues/456)

---

I'm using [reach router](https://github.com/reach/router).

I have some states derived from the URL and different navigate in different callbacks. For example:

```
const App = ({location}) => {
  const { foo, bar } = parseUrl(location.pathname);
  function onFooChange(newFoo) {
      navigate(getUrl({ foo: newFoo, bar });
  }
  function onBarChange(newBar) {
     navigate(getUrl({ foo, bar: newBar });
  }
}
```

The issue is that if we invoke the `onFooChange` and then invoke `onBarChange` right away, the `onBarChange` is still using the OLD `foo` value which overwrites the new `foo` value.

```js
// initially at /foo0/bar0
onFooChange("foo1"); // /foo1/bar0
onBarChange("bar1"); // /foo0/bar1. But the expected is /foo1/bar1
```

How should I work around this? Thanks!

---

some additional thoughts:

We wanted to use the URL as the source of truth. So we didn't want to create local states of `foo` and `bar` locally which might cause conflict between the states in URL and the local state.

Is there something like the `setState` callback so that I can leverage the **previous** state and add incremental changes to it instead of directly overwriting it?

Or I should use the promise returned by the `navigate`? Then I need to maintain a list of promises myself which I tend not to do.

---

Updated [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-forked-mnyw6?file=/example.js:771-1406)

This is a uber simplification of our case.

1. Alice lands on /page1/tab1 (click the Start link at top)
2. Alice clicks the "Nav" button. We redirect her to `/page2/tab1` (with the hope that there is a tab1 in the page2)
3. We found tab1 is not available for page2, so we redirect Alice to the default tab `tab2` of page2, with the "latest" page value in the state. (Expected: page2; Actual: page1)

The issue is that at the time of the second `history.push`, the first `history.push` is not yet done so the `page` state is still `page1`. Thus Alice is redirected to `/page1/tab2` instead of `/page2/tab2`.

I want to use the info in the URL as the source of truth so I don't want to store local state of `page` and `tab`. Instead, I always derive the `page` and `tab` from the `location.pathname`.

Comment: `useEffect` with appropriate dependency is the functional component equivalent of the `setState` callback. Unless you meant using a [Functional State Update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), this allows you to update from the previous state.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, thanks, I knew that. But this question is not related to that.

Comment: "Is there something like the setState callback so that I can leverage the previous state and add incremental changes to it instead of directly overwriting it?" IDK, seems related to me based upon at least a subset of your questions.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I knew that `useEffect` can achieve the `setState` callback. But in my case, I don't want to keep any local state of the info in URL, but only use the URL as the source of truth. And because the reach router is async, the `location` props might be outdated when I call `navigate` twice. So I wonder if second `navigate` call can leverage the parameters I passed into the first `navigate` call.

Comment: No worries. :) Unless the reach router can asynchronously access a routing context (similar to how React enqueues state updates) I don't think this is possible within a single function scope within a single React render cycle. I am not very familiar with Reach, but I would be surprised if it's routing worked drastically different than most other solutions.

Comment: Oh, just reading the docs, it seems Reach Router is essentially merging with React Router v6, so I probably am much more familiar than I thought. I don't think the reach router is async, do you have a source?

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks. I think we need to migrate to React Router. In https://reach.tech/router/api/navigate, it says "Navigate returns a promise so you can await it. It resolves after React is completely finished rendering the next screen.." This can probably imply the async nature of the `navigate` function. If I keep the states of the URL and do the merging myself, I'm worries that the URL and the local state might have conflict (e.g. I called `navigate` while the user changed the URL manually) and I won't know which one is the latest one. :( I'll look at React router for some inspiration.

Comment: Oh, how interesting. Yeah, then I think you'd use normal Promise chaining or `async/await` to handle these two calls asynchronously. React-router v6 is still in alpha, and based upon this [sourcecode](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/f59ee5488bc343cf3c957b7e0cc395ef5eb572d2/packages/react-router/index.js#L380-L410) it doesn't immediately appear to have the asynchronous nature that Reach-Router's `navigate` function does.

Comment: @DrewReese I repro-ed the issue using React Router in https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-forked-mnyw6?file=/example.js

Comment: @DrewReese sure. Really appreciate it!

Comment: This doesn't exactly appear to be a race condition to me. You can see the initial log when the "home" page mounts, `undefined undefined` for `page` and `tab` respectively. When the first push is invoked you navigate to `"/page2/undefined"`, and then a moment later you a push to navigate to `"/undefined/bar2"`. From this function scope this all seems expected behavior. Sorry, but it isn't clear to me the reason for the "double push".

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry for the confusion. Please find my updated comments in the demo. Also updated the comments in this post. Let's start with clicking the "Start" link (/page1/tab1), then click Nav button to trigger the two navigates. The first navigate uses `/page2` but the second navigate still uses `/page1`.

Comment: Your assumptions in step (3) are incorrect. Route transitions are completely synchronous, there's no state to wait to update. This is an enclosure issue, you've enclosed the "page1" value in the callback so when the timer expires you navigate to "/page1/xxx". If you are reasonably expecting navigations to paths with missing tabs or whatever then these checks need to occur *on that page* in an effect hook. Consider this slight [refactor](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-prevent-race-condition-of-different-navigates-f72qu) of your codesandbox.